# Calculator Android Studio

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android studio.I am trying to build a calculator here is my code but the buttons on my calculator are not working Here is the java code.The problem seems to be with clicklistener when i click the button on my android virtual machine the text doesnot changes and the operators are also not working what is the problem in my code if there is any.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private EditText Scr;
private float NumberBf;
private String Operation;
private ButtonClickListener btnClick;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Scr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
int idList[]=                        {

R.id.button,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4,R.id.button5,
R.id.button6,R.id.button7,R.id.button8,
R.id.button9,R.id.button10,R.id.buttonC,
R.id.buttonEq,R.id.buttonAdd,R.id.buttonSub,R.id.buttonDiv,
R.id.buttonDot,R.id.buttonMul};
for(int id:idList)
{
View v = (View) findViewById(id);
v.setOnClickListener(btnClick);

}


}


public void mMath(String str){
NumberBf=Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
Operation=str;
Scr.setText("0");

}
public void getKeyboard(String str)
{
String ScrCurrent = Scr.getText().toString();
ScrCurrent += str;
Scr.setText(ScrCurrent);

}
public void mResult()
{
float NumAf=Float.parseFloat(Scr.getText().toString());
float result=0;
if(Operation.equals("+"))
{
result =NumAf + NumberBf;
}

if(Operation.equals("-"))
{
result =NumAf - NumberBf;
}

if(Operation.equals("*"))
{
result =NumAf * NumberBf;
}

if(Operation.equals("/"))
{
result =NumAf / NumberBf;
}
Scr.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
public void onClick(View v){
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.buttonC:
Scr.setText("0");
NumberBf=0;
Operation="";
break;
case R.id.buttonAdd:
mMath("+");
break;
case R.id.buttonSub:
mMath("-");
break;
case R.id.buttonDiv:
mMath("/");
break;
case R.id.buttonMul:
mMath("*");
break;
case R.id.buttonEq:
mResult();
break;
default :
String numb;
numb = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
getKeyboard(numb);
break;


}

}
}

}
```

And Here is the XML Code.

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:text="0"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:onClick="setContentView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="9"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="."
    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button10"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="C"
    android:id="@+id/buttonC"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSub"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="*"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMul"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonDot"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="/"
    android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDot"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonMul"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonMul"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="="
    android:id="@+id/buttonEq"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDiv"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonDiv"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: `btnClick` seems to be null - it's never instantiated.

Comment: That's what i've been wondering. But it seems he's not getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: You can happily set a null onClickListener, nothing will happen. Try it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit 1: implement OnClickListener

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
```

edit 2:

```
v.setOnClickListener(this);
```

edit 3: add this to the end of the MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {

    }
}
```

This should work. Or you could try to instantiate your btnClick before you set the btnClick as a listener to v.

```
btnClick = new ButtonClickListener();
```

Comment: Could you explain if possible what was the mistake

Comment: the btnClick = new ButtonClickListener() worked? Could u pls accept as answer and upvote. The problem was that the btnClick was never instantiated and therefore btnClick was null.

Comment: no i did not use btnclick= new ButtonClickListener(); but the above three edits worked